# Test website on real iPad on macOS

Tags: xcode

For responsive tests on macOS I'm using Xcode and his simulator, but I found something strange going on on real iPad and I want to test it. Is I possible that I pair my iPad with Mac Mini and test it with Inspect Element like I was testing with the simulator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. On the iOS device, open **Settings** → **Safari** → **Advanced** and enable **Web Inspector**.
2. Connect the device to your Mac over USB and open the website in Safari on your iOS device.
3. On your Mac, open **Safari** → **Preferences** → **Advanced** and enable **Show Develop menu in menu bar**.
4. Choose **Develop** → *your iOS device name* → *your Safari window* to open the web inspector for the iOS device on your Mac.